# Launch a new activity on click of an linkify Phone number

Tags: android-layout

I have a screen on which a weburl and a phone number is linked.
When i clicks the "phone number link" it goes to dialpad and shows the number on dial pad,then if i want to make call i have to press dial button.

What i need to do is to directly make an call when i clicks the phone number itself.I dont want dial pad screen to show to the user.
and keep in mind i have a full textView in which there is some message as well as the link to phone number.
So i think onClick() of textView will not be applicable here.

Please guide me through it if u can.

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this permission line to your AndroidManifest.xml file if you want to auto dial

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

Regards,
Mark